# POST dynamic HTML table values to jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get all the **values** present in my dynamic HTML table and POST the values to AJAX.

I have HTML table like this

[image]

When i press '+' , I can able to add rows dynamically . When i click save, How to POST array values from this HTML table to AJAX, so that i can meanwhile INSERT those values into MYSQL

I have tried getting the 'text' of each td present in my table

```
var rows = $("tbody tr",$("#myTable")).map(function() { 
    return [$("td",this).map(function() { 
      return this.innerHTML;     
    }).get()];
  }).get();
```

This is getting me -> `<input type="text">` and so on.

Comment: Try using jQuery `.serialize()` on the form to create JSON which can be sent in POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are returning the innerHTML, which is... HTML.
you can get the value of a input element with `.val()`
how does this work for you?

```
return $("td input").map(function() { 
  return $(this).val();     
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use serialize function using jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $('#formID').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/pathTo/process_form.php',
                data: $('#formID').serialize()
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var rows = $("td input",$("#myTable")).map(function() { 
    return { name : $(this).attr('name'), value :$(this).val()};
  });
```

and you should get :

```
[ 
  { 
    name : 'inputname',
    value :  'inputval' 
  },
  { ... }
]
```

This would return an array like the .serialize() method

Comment: i am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation - jquery 1.6.1 min.js